# Set month range for second jquery month picker based on first jquery month picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two month pickers "from" and "to". I want to select month in "to" month picker based on "from" month picker. E.g. if Jan-2020 is selected in "from" month picker then "to" month picker should get option from feb-2020 and range should go upto max 3 months i.e. upto April-2020.

```js
$("#dt_st").MonthPicker({
  Button: false,
  MonthFormat: "yy-mm",
  autoclose: true
});
$('body').on('focus', '.end_date', function() {
  var frm_month;
  frm_month = document.getElementById().value;
  $('.end_date').MonthPicker({
    Button: false,
    MonthFormat: "yy-mm",
    MinMonth: frm_month;
    autoclose: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/zorab47/jquery.ui.monthpicker/master/jquery.ui.monthpicker.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='dt_st' />
<input type='text' class='end_date' />
```

I have tried using MinMonth but it is not picking up the value and the calender also doesn't show from end_date. Please tellme what mistake I am making and guide regarding this.

Comment: You seem to be missing an id in `document.getElementById().value`

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `onSelect` to `$("#dt_st").monthpicker` like below. You can update `minDate` `maxDate` with `$('.end_date').monthpicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);`.

You don't need `$('body').on('focus',` just initialize `$('.end_date').monthpicker` after `$("#dt_st").monthpicker`.

Try it below.

```js
$("#dt_st").monthpicker({
  Button: false,
  MonthFormat: "yy-mm",
  autoclose: true,
  onSelect: function(text, inst) {
    var minDate = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth + 1, 1);
    var maxDate = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth + 3, 1);
    $('.end_date').monthpicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
    $('.end_date').monthpicker('option', 'maxDate', maxDate);
  }
});

$('.end_date').monthpicker({
  Button: false,
  MonthFormat: "yy-mm",
  autoclose: true
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/zorab47/jquery.ui.monthpicker/master/jquery.ui.monthpicker.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='dt_st' />
<input type='text' class='end_date' />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OnAfterChooseMonth` event and on first month pick, init second one with proper values.

```
$("#from").MonthPicker({
     OnAfterChooseMonth: function(selectedDate) {
      min_month = selectedDate.getMonth() - new Date().getMonth() 
       $("#to").MonthPicker({
          MinMonth:min_month, 
          MaxMonth:min_month+3,
       });
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rk5x6cpa/)

I used [This](http://jsfiddle.net/kidsysco/JeZap/) fiddle .